# Get values from different column in a groupby based on result

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given a df

```
session article_id  article_type    primary_section
1        nan        nan             nan
1        123        magazine        sport
1        125        tech            laptops
2        126        food            asian_food
2        127        food            euro_food
```

I want to groupby by session_id and get the article_type, primary_section and page in session based on the result of "first" function on article_id
Output:

```
session first_article_id    firt_article_type   primary_section page_in_sess
1        123                magazine            sport           2
2        126                food                asian_food      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and `transform` with `first`:

```
m=df.assign(page_in_sess=df.groupby('session').cumcount()+1)
final=m[m.article_id.eq(m.groupby('session')['article_id'].transform('first'))]
```

---

```
   session  article_id article_type primary_section  page_in_sess
1        1       123.0     magazine           sport             2
3        2       126.0         food      asian_food             1
```

Comment: Thanks, 
It's works but create a duplicates indexes "session"

Comment: so i added final.groupby('session_id').first() and now its perfert.